# не работает Fake-Anti-Aim

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

Написал вот такой код:

```
import pyautogui
from pynput import mouse
from time import sleep
import keyboard

def ex():
    exit()

keyboard.add_hotkey('home', ex)

while True:
    def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
        if button == mouse.Button.left:
            #print('{} at {}'.format('Pressed Left Click' if pressed else 'Released Left Click', (x, y)))
            pyautogui.move(350,350, 0)
            sleep(0.1)
            pyautogui.move(-350,-350, 0)
            return False
        
        

    listener = mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click)
    listener.start()
    listener.join()
```

по идеи после выстрела камера в игре должна резко смещаться на 350, 350 пикселей и через 0.1 секунд возвращаться обратно, но в игре ничего подобного не происходит, PS: игра CS:GO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Установите паузу в 0 сек после каждого вызова `PyAutoGUI`:

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.PAUSE = 0
```

И отключите *Fail-Safe*:

```
pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False
```

*Не забудьте отключить прямой ввод мыши в игре.*

Comment: можно обьяснение, как это работает? и что это меняет?

Comment: @Selasi, это отключит паузы между каждым действием. Возможно вам нужно будет отключить прямой ввод в игре.